# Gas to solid heating?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity, convection, heat-conduction

I am doing a study on the phenomenon of pyrolysis. This is purely a study of the underlying physics. Generally, in practice, pyrolysis feedstock is heated conductively but we are examining the energy requirement of heating the feedstock with a gas.

I am wondering what equations I could apply for a moving gas at a flow rate (X kg/s) over a quantity of feedstock (y kg) made up of particles of feedstock (d mm in diameter). The temperature difference between the feedstock and the gas would likely be around 770K (303K and 1073K) and the pyrolysis temperature would likely be around 770K. I'm wondering what a model would look like for this situation as the only similar situation I can find is baking, which isn't of much use.

*This question is specifically about the underlying physics of steam/gas heated pyrolysis and not the application in engineering*

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to be the *outcome* of your model. What *response variables* do you expect from your input?

Comment: I’m not seeing the research effort that you’ve at least looked at (and rejected?) the existing models in the ample literature on pyrolysis.

Comment: What exactly is the geometric arrangement of the solid relative to the gas?  what contains the solid (is it levitating in space)?

Comment: Hi all, apologies but I cannot go into the details regarding pyrolysis since my last question was taken down for being about "engineering" and not physics. I have rejected many models since the gas and solid are both flowing through the system. The particles and the gas are in a partially filled auger which is transporting the solid while the gas is being added from the sides of the auger. The outcome is an energy requirement to heat a unit of solid to 500C from 30C using gas at 800C at a flow rate of X kg/s.